# Kendo UI Combobox - Dropdown closes immediately in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

Here is my code. It works fine on chrome but in firefox as i click the dropdown it appears for a sec and then disappears. Where am I mistaken ?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="deliveryaddress">Adress 
    <span id="limitMsg" style="font-size:12px !important; font-weight: bold !important; color:red !important;"></span>
  </label>
  @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
  .Name("deliveryadress")
  .DataTextField("Text")
  .DataValueField("Value")
  .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
  .MinLength(3)
  .Placeholder("Börja skriva gatuadress för att söka...")
  .Suggest(true)
  .AutoBind(false)
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;", @class = "deliveryformclass" })
  .DataSource(source =>
  {
  source.Read(read =>
  {
  read.Action("SearchAdress", "Home");
  })
  .ServerFiltering(true);
  })
  )
</div>
```

Comment: What language is that code block in? It isn't native javascript. Is it a template? Or part of a framework?

Comment: oh durr, probably Kendo, i bet.

Comment: @Anthony Yes it is [Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC](http://www.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc)

Comment: @Sara Check this [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-opens-and-then-closes-with-3-22-releases). They talk about similar problem... can it be same problem?

Comment: Works for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/krustev/rp772/  which version of Firefox are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem but in chrome, I notice that it happens when your combobox is all the way in the bottom without enough space for the dropdown to open. Try adding a space at the bottom with an empty div and see if it works. It worked for me.

Hope this helps :)